# Is the ㅆ in 씌 palatalized or not?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

The passive form of 쓰다 is 쓰이다, whose contraction is 씌다. 씌 also appears in 씌우다, which is the causative form of 쓰다.

The 표준 발음법 states that ㅢ following a consonant is pronounced as [ㅣ]. That means 씌 is pronounced as [씨]. But I'm still unsure because the 외래어 표기법 states that both [si] and [ɕi] are to be transcribed to 시.

Is the ㅆ in 씌 palatalized or not? Or in other words, is ㅆ in 씌 [s͈] or [ɕ͈]?

Comment: Although you mentioned 외래어 표기법, I assume you know that 씌우다 is *not* 외래어. You can refer to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%94%8C%EC%9A%B0%EB%8B%A4) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Korean) pages to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Standard Pronunciation(표준 발음법), 씌 is pronounced equivalently as [씨]. So it is palatalized in the same manner as 씨.

I'm not sure why 외래어 표기법 confuses you there.